# LinkedHashMap or two separate arrays in java

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I have two arrays of predefined length, let us say 8, which contains related data. I can arrange them in such a way that array1[0] has corresonding mapping at array2[0]. That is key value pairs are at the same index in both arrays. In such a case, for iterating the array, I can either use a for loop like below

```
for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
  int array1Val = array1[i];
  String array2Val = array2[i];
    //some code
 }
```

Is this approach gud? Or is it better to use linked hashmap instead and loop using

```
 map.entrySet()
```

Complexity wise and efficiency wise which is a better approach?

Comment: Efficiency depends on the upper bound on the length of your data and the kind of operations you're going to do on that data.

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections.aspx Jon Skeet has a blog post about this anti-pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Rule of thumb: When you are considering creating corresponding arrays, then it's time to create a class for that corresponding data, and create an array of that class.  This is the clearest, most readable, object-oriented way to store your corresponding data in objects in Java.  (It doesn't have to be called "Data".)

```
class Data {
   private int value1;
   private String value2;
   // Any other arrays?  Make another value here.
   // Constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Then declare an array of that class, and store objects in it here.

```
Data[] mydata = new Data[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   mydata[i] = new Data();  // and you can then initialize the Data object too.
}
```

Then one `for` loop can access each `Data` object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   Data data = mydata[i];
   // Extract values here.
}
```

(Or you can use the enhanced "foreach" loop also.)

```
for (Data data : mydata) {
   // Extract values here.
}
```

Comment: For the record, there are a lot of times when a collection from `java.util` is much preferred vs. a `java.lang.Array`.  I would default to an `ArrayList` instead of defaulting to an `Array`, and only use an `Array` once all performance characteristics were known and it became clear that the performance would be better with Array.  But almost always, the flexibility of one of the Collections (which can be resized cheaply and without requiring a new object reference) is preferred to the minor performance benefits of an `Array`.

Comment: He asked which is a better way (in objective terms) of consuming data.. two arrays or one map.. simple question.. no need to go off the topic about data modeling and when to create a POJO.

Comment: @Tim An `ArrayList` of `Data` can certainly be used here too.  But the point of my answer is to create a class to hold an attribute for each "corresponding array", so I think that moving to an array of the new class was the cleanest explanation, without adding in extraneous information about possibly using `ArrayList`s.

Comment: @user1500191 I would use an array (or an `ArrayList`) of a new class over "corresponding arrays" or a `Map` here.  I don't think that suggesting another solution is "off topic".

Comment: @rgettman Agreed, but since the question seems to indicate a Java beginner (or a newly transitioned C++ developer), I think it's worth nudging the OP towards the most useful container for those objects in addition to just suggesting using those objects.

Comment: @user1500191 "Would you rather be shot in the head or the foot?"  "Actually, I'd rather point the gun downrange so we actually hit the target."  I don't think this suggestion is off-topic.

Comment: ok ok go ahead kill the messenger lol... i updated my answer based on your feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a map.

In terms of performance, you are iterating over the length of the data structure.

so its only o(n)

reading from a map is o(1), reading from an array is also o(1)

so really no difference in performance.

But in terms of readability and maintainability its better to have a single "map" data structure then two array data structures that need to be consumed/used in a "special way" (in this case you need to remember that array1[0] maps to array2[0]. That makes the code less readable and more complicated than it has to be.

Keep your code clean, easy to read, and simple, use a map:

Here is are ways to loop thru a map in java:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
    // ...
}

for (Object value : map.values()) {
    // ...
}
```

[UPDATE]

In response to people who suggest "hey create a Class"...

Please ask yourself "who needs to consume this data"?

If the data is only relevant to an internal method, then I suggest using an anonymous class like here:

```
public void myMethod(String param1, String param2) {
    class MyAnonymousClass {
        String data1;
        String data2;
    }
    MyAnonymousClass anonymous = new MyAnonymousClass();
    anonymous.data1 = param1;
    anonymous.data2 = param2;
}
```

If the data is only relevant to the internals of another Class then create a private static inner class.

```
 pubic class SomeClass {
    private static class MyDataContainer {

    }
 }
```

Just be aware of these choices when creating classes.

Cheers!

Comment: I'd only consider using a Map in this way if one of the attributes is truly an identifier (and is unique); you certainly can't use this approach with `firstName` and `lastName`, for example.  And it also breaks down as soon as the OP has a third attribute to index this way.  So there are some limited circumstances where I might choose this because I didn't want to make a separate object, but it's not as broadly applicable as the object-oriented approach.